# My UITable is re-using cells when it shouldn't!

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController` which has two sections. The first section shows a single cell with centered text, saying `Add a new Slide`. The second section show the current slides.

When a user taps on the `Add a new slide` cell, a new `UITableVeiwController` is pushed onto the stack that shows an editor. If the user saves the new slide (by tapping save), the cell is added to the data source and the editor is popped from the stack.

I have two problems:

1. When the editor is popped, if a cell was deleted before `Add a new slide` was tapped, the old cell shows up instead of the new one. Popping the `UITableViewController` (by tapping the automatically generated back button) fixes this, but I'd like this to not happen at all. (Originally, popping the table did not update after popping the editor, so I added `[self.tableView reloadData];` to the `viewDidAppear` method.)
2. After a certain number of slides, the last slide on the list becomes the `Add a new slide` cell. I know that the data is being entered properly because another part of the app, which uses the same data source, updates correctly. The table supports editing in the second section, and when you swap the order of the cells, it behaves correctly behind the scenes, but the wrong cell is still there.

What could be going on?

**Here's some of my code:**

*Note that as I was gearing to post my code, I noticed a mismatch of the braces. The check for* `cell==nil` *seems to encompass the second part of the code which determines the content of the cells. This fixes the label of the cells in the second section of the table, but the style is still wrong. I've since fixed the code, but the original is posted here.*

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        if ([indexPath section] == 0 ) {
            cell = [[[MBTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }else if([indexPath section] == 1){
            cell = [[[MBTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    }

    if ([indexPath section] == 0) {
        [cell.textLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
        [cell.textLabel setText:@"Add a New Slide"];
    }else if([indexPath section] == 1){
        NSArray *storedViewsInfo = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[kSettings arrayForKey:@"views"]];

        if ([[[storedViewsInfo objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] valueForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"announcement"]) {
            [cell.detailTextLabel setText:@"Custom Announcement"];
            [cell.textLabel setText:[[[storedViewsInfo objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] valueForKey:@"info"] valueForKey:@"text"]];
        }

        [storedViewsInfo release];
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];

    }
    }
    return cell;

}
```

Comment: can you post `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing the code, first thing that comes to mind is checking if you've given your custom cells different identifiers in your `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;` method?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"CellIdentifier1";
    static NSString *Cellidentifier2 = @"CellIdentifier2";

    if (indexPath.section == kAddSlideSection) {
        CustomCell *cellType1 = (CustomCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
        ...
    } else {
        CustomCell *cellType2 = (CustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
        ...
    }
}
```

Also it might be worth considering implementing a delegate method that gets called when your user finishes adding the new slide - i.e. if successful call `[self.tableview reloadData]` from that method instead of in `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: This fixes the bugs, but suddenly, I'm having stability/performance issues. What's going on?

Comment: What sort of issues? Is it crashing and if so where?

Comment: I'm getting memory warnings when I try to open my settings panel (even though it has an unrelated root view.). I think it has to do with the number of slides I'm trying to show. The cells are generated based on info from a plist, which is saved in NSUserDefaults. I think it could be the sheer size of the plist once I hit 10+ cells. Perhaps I should look into Core Data... Think that would help?

Comment: Sounds like it might be the case! PS: be patient with CoreData, it takes a bit of time to wrap your head around it but when you do you will love it forever after :)