# Please explain this weird way of setting cell accessory

Tags: iphone, accessorytype

I saw the following line of code [here](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/7391-uitableviewcell-repeat-every-12-rows.html#post33258) while Googling for an answer to [another question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381768/my-uitable-is-re-using-cells-when-it-shouldnt).

```
cell.accessoryType = (UITableViewCellAccessoryNone + UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) - cell.accessoryType;
```

It seems, from that thread, that the code works. I'm just wondering, isn't that code redundant ? If you know the `accessoryType`, why subtract it from that expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the accessoryType was UITableViewCellAccessoryNone, then the net of the expression would be setting it to UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark.

If the accessoryType was UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark, then the net of the expression would be setting it to UITableViewCellAccessoryNone.

It's just a shortcut to saying

```
if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark
else if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone
```

Definitely an example of obfuscated code... I'd avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

Given that this code is toggling between `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` and `UITableViewCellAccessoryNone` and is attempting to be concise, another alternative -- which I find clearer -- would be:

```
cell.accessoryType ^= UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark|UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
```

This statement is more clear in its intent and obviates the need for a conditional statement -- which might or might not be useful depending on how frequently it is called.

Comment: Less readable than the other answer or the original statement in question? I look at the original statement and think to myself: "why on Earth are they adding bitmasks?" With regards to the accepted answer, I suppose it's a matter of style: you'll often find statements like the one in my answer littered throughout code written by EEs -- perhaps a different approach to programming, its merit (or otherwise) debatable.

Comment: Well, at least you didn't suggest a ternary operator.